# Remove files from commit made by git merge

Tags: git

I am quite newbie with git.

I have master branch and feature branch. I merged master branch to my feature branch ( as pull request complained about conflicts ).

However the merge commited files i do not want to track ( from `.idea` folder ). So my commit looks something like:

```
  .idea
     ...
  .src
     ...
```

Now if i push the commit i push also files i do not want on remote. Is there a way how to remove these files from the commit and keep other files commited?

Thanks for help!

Comment: You cannot remove files from a commit. You cannot alter a commit in any way! If you could, Git would not be much use. You can effectively _delete_ the merge commit if you like, thus undoing the merge (as long as it's on your machine and you haven't pushed it), and now you can rethink what to do from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You could list the files in that `idea` directory in the `.gitignore` file.

Alternatively, you could delete the files entirely so they are no longer tracked if that's what you desire:

```
git rm -r --cached <folder>
```

Note that files will be removed (including for other developers' machines when they next perform `git pull`).

Comment: Note that Git ignore has no effect at all on already tracked files, it’s not an alternative to committing deleting the files - it’s part of the same process.